# How can I get my saved html file to be rendered rather than displaying the raw html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, html-rendering

I have html files saved in the App_Data folder of a Web API app. A companion client (Winforms) app sends an email with a link that allows the user to click that link and view these html files in their browser like so:

```
// Client Winforms app code
internal static bool EmailGeneratedReports(string emailAddr)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = String.Format("duckbillP Reports generated {0}", GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());
        mailItem.To = emailAddr;
        string rptLinks = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}/api/{1}/{2}/{3}\" target=\"_blank\">Price Compliance Report Online</a>", ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.SERVER_BASE_ADDRESS, "Platypus", "gramps", "201507"); // hardcoding year and month for now
        mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format("<html><body><p>Your duckbillP reports are attached. You can also view them online here:</p>{0}</body></html>", rptLinks);
        FileInfo[] rptsToEmail = GetLastReportsGenerated();
        foreach (var file in rptsToEmail)
        {
            mailItem.Attachments.Add(String.Format("{0}\\{1}", uniqueFolder, file.Name));                  
        }
        mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mailItem.Display(false);
    }
    catch (System.Exception sysex)
    {
        String sysexDetail = String.Format(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, sysex.Message,
            Environment.NewLine, sysex.Source, sysex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(sysexDetail);
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

The Get code in the Web API app runs just fine; this is what is called when the link is clicked:

```
// Web API (server) Controller code
[Route("{unit}/{begindate}")]
public string Get(string unit, string begindate)
{
    string _unit = unit;
    string _begindate = String.Format("{0}01", PlatypusWebReportsConstsAndUtils.HyphenizeYYYYMM(begindate));
    string appDataFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");

    string htmlSummaryFilename = string.Format("platypusSummary_{0}_{1}.html", _unit, _begindate);
    string fullSummaryPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, htmlSummaryFilename);

    string htmlDetailFilename = string.Format("platypusDetail_{0}_{1}.html", _unit, _begindate);
    string fullDetailPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, htmlDetailFilename);

    String summaryHtmlFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fullSummaryPath);
    String detailHtmlFromFile = File.ReadAllText(fullDetailPath);
    return String.Format("{0}<br/><br/>{1}", summaryHtmlFromFile, detailHtmlFromFile);
}
```

I was hoping that the html returned would render in the browser in the normal way, but instead of that it just displays the raw html (including all the angle brackets and html keywords, etc.). IOW, it appears if I'm viewing HTML in Notepad, rather than in a browser.

How can I see to it that the HTML returned by the GET method displays as intended?

To be perfectly clear, I don't want the user to see stuff like this:

```
<h1>This is heading 1 (Candara)</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2 (Georgia)</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3 (Tahoma)</h3>
<p class="candara">This is a Candara 1.1em paragraph</p>
<p class="segoe">This is a Segoe UI paragraph</p>
<p class="tahoma">This is a Tahoma paragraph</p>
<p class="georgia">This is a Georgia 1.1em paragraph</p>
```

...but rather the rendered HTML like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should tell the browser that you're sending HTML content. Something like this should work:

```
// Send an HTTP message instead of a string.
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit, string begindate)
{
    // Here you process the data...

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            String.Format("{0}<br/><br/>{1}", summaryHtmlFromFile, detailHtmlFromFile), 
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            "text/html"
        )
    };
}
```